# Flutter | Build functions must never return null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The error message is quite straightforward,
I have tried return Container(); in else still, it does not work out

FutureBuilder reviewFutureBuilder() {

```
return FutureBuilder<OrdersModel>(
  future: _futureReviewModel,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {

    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
     return Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('$snapshot.error'),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

[this is my error in the studio](https://ibb.co/x62qMqt)

[this my mobile UI error](https://ibb.co/tLn4p7p)

Comment: You haven't returned anything in the first "if" statement. XD

Comment: Actually, I have returned but it was huge code so I thought to skip that part.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Debjeet No problem, but from next time, kindly make sure that you specify that in a comment at least. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by wrapping snapshot.haserror and return CircularProgress in a container, here is how I solved it.

```
else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('$snapshot.error'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no usable example provided i will forward you to the documentation.
[FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

In the middle of the page you will find a interactive example.
As i dont know the full function of your code i have provided a working example:

First you need Data in your if-check:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {

}
```

Becomes:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return Center(
    child: Column(<SOME DATA>),
  );
}
```

Complete example:

```
FutureBuilder reviewFutureBuilder() {
  return FutureBuilder<OrdersModel>(
  future: _futureReviewModel,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return Center(
    child: Column(<SOME DATA>),
  );
  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('$snapshot.error'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } else {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  },
);
}
```